# Get treeviewitem during drag & drop operation between two treeviews

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I am doing drag and drop operation between two treeviews.
In Target treeview(Drop Treeview),this treeview is populated using drives and files in the System.
How can i get the treeviewitem to which i want to drop dragged item in the target treeview?
I am using the below code in drop event of target treeview

```
    private void TargetTreeview_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Node item = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Node)) as Node;
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        Point Start = e.GetPosition(TargetTreeview_Drop);
        HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(TargetTreeview_Drop, Start);
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.VisualHit is FrameworkElement)
            {
                FrameworkElement Target = result.VisualHit as FrameworkElement;
                object data = Target.DataContext;
            }
        }


    }
```

In the above code i cannot convert the object "data" to treeviewitem.
If i convert "data" to treeviewitem means it is "null".

Can anyone help me to get the target treeviewitem to which i want to drop the dragged item.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this difrently, first off in the first treeview i would have a Click or MouseCliCk event handler and save that clicked in a global variable

```
TreeNode tn = null;
treeView1.Click += (s,e)=>{
    tn=e.Node;
};
```

And in the second treeview i would have in the drop event something like this(dont know the correct syntax fro the drop event but you will get the idea)

```
treeView2.Drop += (s,e) =>{

    if(tn!=null){

         treeView2.Nodes.Add(tn.Clone());
         //or whatever you want to do
    }
};
```

Hope it was clear

Comment: Hai Vajura There is no TreeNode class in wpf.TreeNode class is existed in     Winforms .I am asking in wpf TreeViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the sender object as a TreeView, then use SelectedItem of the TreeView. If it is a TreeViewItem then cast it as such.

```
    var tree = sender as TreeView;

    // ... Determine type of SelectedItem.
    if (tree.SelectedItem is TreeViewItem)
    {
        // ... Handle a TreeViewItem.
        var item = tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
        this.Title = "Selected header: " + item.Header.ToString();
    }
    else if (tree.SelectedItem is string)
    {
        // ... Handle a string.
        this.Title = "Selected: " + tree.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```